# How can I maintain an iOS Framework initially installed via CocoaPods but modified manually later on?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, maintainability

I'm currently working on a iOS (Swift) app for which I installed a few Frameworks via Cocoapods.

I have been facing a few issues with one of the frameworks and decided to tweak its code manually to run some tests and see if I could make things work.

I ended up figuring out a way to achieve what I wanted but I had to add a couple files in that framework as well as modify a few others.

This is the first time I do this and I'm almost certain this is no the best way to do things but I wanted to get some advices on how I can maintain that framework (that is behaving the way I want) in the future?

If I run "pod install" again, I suppose the framework and my changes will be overridden...

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Fork the repo and make your changes then point your podfile at your fork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the source repo (probably on GitHub) and fork it to your own account.  Check out that repo and make your changes.

*Optionally* I would recommend making your adjustments to the code reusable so others can also use your tweaked version (make it configurable so they can turn the additional functionality on or off) and then submit a pull request back to the original repo.

If you don't want to do that you can point your Podfile directly to your customised repo using the following format:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
```

Or you could look at creating your own CocoaPod (either by publishing to CocoaPods public specs repo or creating your own specs repo).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try. I hacked things together for now so probably not public-ready just yet but will see when I refactor.